# Postgres incomplete schema tables dump using pg-dump

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, pg-dump

I have postgres 9.6 database which having 20GB data. I am taking dump using following command -

```
 pg_dump -U postgres -d test > test.sql
```

Now the schema tables are having size like 12GB.

[image: schema tables]

I have taken dump another way:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -d iedb -Fc > iedb.dmp
```

still only 2.3gb data exported in dump file. Its giving me following output after restoration -

[image: pg_schema_after_restore]

I have tried using single schema but its not taking proper data.
Can someone help me out with this. My data is stored on object schemas which is part of database. I am not able to export same amount of data to other server. Is their any config parameter regarding export data limit?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I don't have the answer, but the community of [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) might be able to help you. Someone already voted to move your question to there, so you will not have to cross-post to get an answer, it will probably soon be moved automatically!

Comment: It might be that your table was bloated and the "clean" insert simply shrunk it to the real size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal for a dump to be smaller than the original database. For one, indexes take up no space in a dump, they become a single `CREATE INDEX` line.

Restoring a dump will also result in a smaller database, because the rows will be packed and there is no bloat. A certain amount of bloat in tables and indexes is normal.

I'd say there is nothing to worry.

Comment: thanks for the help. some of the tables are bloat and auto vacuum is not enabled.

Comment: Enable autovacuum. It should never be disabled, except maybe temporarily for bulk loading and similar operations.